# One-to-Many custom schema mapping in Corda Persistence

Tags: hibernate, corda

In Corda persistence, how to write a schema to map array of nested objects as children inside a parent?

I am looking at this document https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html and managed to create simple, non-nested properties of the state object mapped to the columns in the database. However, it is still not working for list objects as children.

The current code reads below and it is throwing error. What are output_index and transaction_id columns?

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (child_table [parent]) must have same
>   number of columns as the referenced primary key (parent_table
>   [output_index,transaction_id])

```
package com.template

import net.corda.core.identity.AbstractParty
import net.corda.core.schemas.MappedSchema
import net.corda.core.schemas.PersistentState
import net.corda.core.serialization.CordaSerializable
import javax.persistence.*


object TestSchema

@CordaSerializable
object ChildSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = TestSchema.javaClass, version = 1, mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentChild::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "child_table",
            indexes = arrayOf(Index(name = "id_child_idx", columnList = "child_id")))
    class PersistentChild(
            @Column(name = "child_id")
            var childId: Int,

            @ManyToOne 
            var parent: ParentSchemaV1.PersistentParent

    ) : PersistentState() {
        constructor() : this(0, ParentSchemaV1.PersistentParent())
    }
}

@CordaSerializable
object ParentSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = TestSchema.javaClass, version = 1, mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentParent::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "parent_table",
            indexes = arrayOf(Index(name = "id_idx", columnList = "id")))
    class PersistentParent(   

            @Column(name = "id", length = 100)
            var id: String,

            @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
            var children: List<ChildSchemaV1.PersistentChild>

    ) : PersistentState() {
        constructor() : this("", ArrayList<ChildSchemaV1.PersistentChild>())
    }
}
```

generateMappedObject function in the Corda state is not included here because it is quite straightforward and I don't think that part is causing issue.

Please note the code above is simplified version of the actual code and hasn't been tested.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code Snippet suggests that you have two schemas  ChildSchemaV1 and ParentSchemaV1 for the same single Corda State(Curious to know how you mapped these schemas in you state). A suggestion would be to use single schema for a particular state .

Also in the Relational mapping of child to parent

```
        @ManyToOne 
        var parent: ParentSchemaV1.PersistentParent
```

Instead Use the below Code Snippet where it maps to the State as your joining columns must be output_index,transaction_id as these are primary keys for Persisted State

```
        @ManyToOne 
        var cordaStateVar: CordaSate
```

Check the complete Code below from the official Corda Site .

```
@CordaSerializable
object SchemaV1 : MappedSchema(schemaFamily = Schema::class.java, version = 1, 
mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentParentToken::class.java, 
PersistentChildToken::class.java)) {

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_data")
class PersistentParentToken(
        @Column(name = "owner")
        var owner: String,

        @Column(name = "issuer")
        var issuer: String,

        @Column(name = "amount")
        var currency: Int,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linear_id: UUID,

         @JoinColumns(JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"), JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"))

        var listOfPersistentChildTokens: MutableList<PersistentChildToken>
) : PersistentState()

@Entity
@CordaSerializable
@Table(name = "child_data")
class PersistentChildToken(
        @Id
        var Id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

        @Column(name = "owner")
        var owner: String,

        @Column(name = "issuer")
        var issuer: String,

        @Column(name = "amount")
        var currency: Int,

        @Column(name = "linear_id")
        var linear_id: UUID,

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PersistentParentToken::class)
        var persistentParentToken: TokenState

) : PersistentState()
```